# Error with set Method C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, dynamic-arrays, mutators

I am new to C++ and I am getting an error.

Basically I have a variable `char myName[150]` and have a method called

```
void setName(char myNames) {
  this->myName = myNames;
}
```

My error is myName[150] is not equal to myNames. I think the compiler is trying to say incompatible types however I don't know how to fix my code.

Also, I'm interested in storing two sets of values, multiple times. For example, `{[0,10], [5,15], [6,69]...}` - would I be right in having something like this

```
int **d[]; /dynamic array - grows in size and not fixed
void setValues(int a, int b){
  //NEED HELP WITH IMPLEMENTATION HERE
}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out with my errors and questions. I am very keen on learning this C++ language - I really like C++ and C, and wish I learnt them as my first ever programming language

Comment: You need to stop using square brackets and asterisks and start using `std::string`.

Comment: @KerrekSB it has to be char because I want to limit the user input stored. I don't want the user to input a long name for example, as it is not convienient

Comment: But now you're *always* paying 150 chars even for short names! Limits as you describe should be enforced elsewhere.

Comment: @KerrekSB sorry, I'm trying to keep up to 150 chars per username.

Comment: Most usernames won't even be close to that length so you're just wasting a bunch of memory. You're better off using `std::string` not just for saving memory but for objects that handle all the memory management themselves and provides a lot of useful common functionality and makes for much cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you that the types are different: `myName` is a `char[150]`, but `myNames` is a `char`. That assignment doesn't work. Maybe you meant:

```
void setName(const char* name) {
    strncpy(myName, name, sizeof(myName));
}
```

or

```
std::string myName;
void setName(const std::string& name) {
    myName = name;
}
```

or some equivalent.

For the second question, just use `std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >`.

Comment: Maybe he definitely did not mean something so terrible and pointless as C-style strings.